# Install Twig plugin in Aptana studio 3

Tags: twig, text-editor, aptana3

I want to install twig plugin in Aptana studio 3 but didn't find any jar file or specific links needed for installation.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the repository for the Eclipse twig Plugin featuring PDT

Update Site for Eclipse http://p2-dev.pdt-extensions.org/

Add this to your software sites

It's inside the "Text Editors / Productivity Tools" category:

It has to be installed alongside PDT

Good luck

Comment: I can find something in preferences about text editors, but nothing about Productivity tools. And I can't see any mention of PDT anywhere. Can you be a bit more specific about what exactly we need to do please?

Comment: When you are adding the link above as a new software source. You will be able to install this via *install software* that's where you have to add this.